# Why is my TXT/SPF record(s) being ignored?

Tags: dns, smtp, record, spam, spf

I'm having trouble trying to configure a SPF record in the DNS settings of my domain.

I have created a TXT record with a what should be a valid SPF record.

When I test my domain's DNS setting using http://mxtoolbox.com/domain/ it reports that:

A Valid TXT Record was not found

and

A Valid SPF Record was not found

even though I have definitely set a TXT record and I'm pretty sure the SPF record is valid.

Here are the DNS settings I am using:
[image]

Besides this the SMTP seems to be functioning properly.

Answer (score 2):

I found some doc about it here
for the txt record:

```
http://mxtoolbox.com/problem/spf/txt-record
```

for the spf record:

```
http://mxtoolbox.com/problem/spf/spf-record
```

you can find a tool to check your spf record validity at the bottom of both page. Hope it helps

Comment: Note that SPF DNS RR is not appropriate for SPFv1 anymore - see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7208#section-14.1

Answer (score 0):

Hi I Know im late on this forum but for purpose of other researchers 
i found that removing the inverted commas fixes the problem